# Why regex+grouping fails test?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex to replace placeholders in a template file.

I have this method:

```
public static String processTemplate(String template, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    Matcher m = PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN.matcher(template);
    String message = template;
    boolean matches = m.matches();

    if (matches) {
        for (int i = 1; i < m.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
            message = message.replaceAll(m.group(i), attributes.get(m.group(i)));
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

with this pattern:

```
    private static final Pattern PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\{.*?})");
```

But this test fails:

```
@Test
public void templates() {
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("${wobble}", "wobble");
    String result = processTemplate("wibble ${wobble}", attributes);
    assertEquals("wibble wobble", result);
}
```

And I don't know why. It seems that the 'match' is returning false.

Comment: The test is only a single line, but the prod code is multiline

Comment: You do not have `^` nor `$` in the pattern, the `Pattern.MULTILINE` will not have any effect on your pattern. The `Pattern.DOTALL` will force `.` match newline symbols, and you have `.` in the pattern.

Comment: your template "${wobble}" doesn't have any newline in it

Comment: Thanks, but the multiline/newline stuff is misleading. I've just removed it. It has no bearing on the test passing or failing (I've just tried it).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the \\$ doesn't mean end of line? Should it be "$" without "\\"?

Comment: No, it's not an end of line symbol, nor is the problem related to line endings. I have a template in which I'm replacing placeholders. I've just clarified the question.

Comment: maybe "(\\$\\{[^}]*})" would be better?

Comment: can you print out the 2 args you pass to replaceAll for debugging? What are they?

Comment: This would find multiple instances of the ^ and/or } symbol -- I don't have any of those within my templates. I've just tried this to see if I've misunderstood it, but I haven't. Why do you think this char-class would help?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't find a match, so the loop and replace aren't executed

Comment: `boolean matches = m.find();` and `message = message.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(m.group(i)), attributes.get(m.group(i)));` would also make it work. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/LNQcBV).

Comment: Actually, this is simpler than the accepted answer -- if I'd had it as an answer I probably would have accepted it in preference because its closer to my original intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can process your regex:

```
private static final Pattern PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?}");

public static String processTemplate(String template, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    Matcher m = PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN.matcher(template);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
       if (attributes.containsKey(m.group()))
           m.appendReplacement(sb, attributes.get(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then call it as:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put("${wobble}", "wobble");
String result = processTemplate("wibble ${wobble}", attributes);
//=> "wibble wobble"
```

Changes are:

1. Use `matcher.find()` instead `matcher.matches()`
2. Use `matcher.appendReplacement()` to append each replacement into a buffer
3. Finally call `matcher.appendTail()` to append remaining text

Comment: There was a second problem, that you've solved with this solution too. It turns out that my replaceAll wouldn't have worked as written either, but your solution bypasses that problem nicely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using [`Matcher.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) which, as the docs say:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

So when you pass in `"wibble ${wobble}"` the match fails because the `"wibble "` bit isn't accounted for in your regex.

Instead of `Matcher.matches()` you should use [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) which will find the next partial match.

Comment: You're absolutely right, this was the problem I was trying to solve. There was a further problem in the code though that I hadn't noticed, which was that the replaceAll wouldn't have worked either. This was noticed and solved by the accepted answer.